# Remote IP Camera Video on multiple Android devices

Tags: android, stream, camera, ip

One of my clients has installed an IP camera (D-Link S930L) in a church and wishes to share video with others using an Android App.

The catch is that, multiple (a few hundred) users will be connecting to the service at the same time and he also wishes to stream the audio from the network camera to the android app.

How can I go about this?  All other topics that I found involved directly streaming video to just a few users. What controls do I need to use in the Android app to display the stream and how would I be able to support a few hundred users? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following links were found to be working with the camera:

http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/mjpeg.cgi (Motion JPEG)

http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/IMAGE.JPG (JPEG)

http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/VIDEO.CGI (Video)

http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/image/jpeg.cgi (JPEG)

Thanks

Comment: Your principal problem has nothing to do with Android and everything to do with the camera. That camera is unlikely to have the horsepower to support "a few hundred" simultaneous users. Hence, you will need to figure out some sort of server solution that can read in the stream and echo it out to your audience. Once you figure out *that* problem, then roll back to how you can view the results from Android. BTW, the actual product number appears to be DCS-930L.

Comment: The one thing that really would be android-related would be that it would probably be helpful if whatever server solution was chosen transcoded to a streaming format supported by android's built in (usually hw accelerated) video engine.  There are apps on the market that can view other formats such as MJPEG, but they consume more power with software decoding, and those formats tend to be less efficient of bandwidth (they are chosen for simplicity of the encoder, not for bandwidth efficiency)

Answer (score 0):

My Friend have done somethin for me in C# :

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace kamera
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        //private static String imageUrl = "http://cam-kk-03/now.jpg";
        private static String imageUrl=null;
        private static Thread t ;  
        private static Image webImage;
        private static List<String> kamere;
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        private static int intervalOsvezevanja=3000; //ms
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ////timer k pokliče funkcijo vsake x sekund
            //AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            //TimerCallback tcb = updatePicture;
            //System.Threading.Timer stateTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(tcb, autoEvent, 0, 200);


            t = new Thread(updatePicture);
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();

            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); // Everytime timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
            timer.Interval = (intervalOsvezevanja) ;             // Timer will tick every 0.05 seconds
            timer.Enabled = true;                       // Enable the timer
            timer.Start();                              // Start the timer

            //skrijemo formo za dodajanje kamer
            panelDodajKamero.Hide();

            //inicializacija
            kamere = new List<String>();
            tbNaslovKamere.Text =  "cam-kk-";
            preberiDatoteko();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = webImage;
        }

        ~Form1() {
            //t.Join();
            t.Abort();
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();
        }

        private void updatePicture(object stateInfo)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (imageUrl != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        WebRequest requestPic = WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
                        WebResponse responsePic = requestPic.GetResponse();
                        webImage = Image.FromStream(responsePic.GetResponseStream());
                        //webImage.Save("C:\\Users\\Public\\kamera\\kamera" + fileName + ".jpg");
                    }
                    catch{}
                }
                Thread.Sleep(intervalOsvezevanja);
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (menuStrip1.Visible)
            {
                menuStrip1.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                menuStrip1.Show();
            }
        }

        private void menjajKamero(String camAddr)
        {
            if (camAddr.Contains("http"))
            {
                imageUrl = camAddr;
            }
            else
            {
                imageUrl = "http://" + camAddr + "/now.jpg";
            }
        }

        private void btDodajKamero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String webAddres;
            if (tbNaslovKamere.Text.Contains("http"))
            {
                webAddres = tbNaslovKamere.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                webAddres = "http://" + tbNaslovKamere.Text + "/now.jpg";
            }
            if (RemoteFileExists(webAddres))
            {
                if (!kamere.Contains(tbNaslovKamere.Text) && !kamere.Contains(webAddres))
                {
                    kamere.Add(tbNaslovKamere.Text);
                    //kamere.Add(webAddres);
                }
                menjajKamero(tbNaslovKamere.Text);
                //menjajKamero(webAddres);
                panelDodajKamero.Hide();
                izpisKamer();
                tbNaslovKamere.Text = "cam-kk-";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ne najdem Kamere");
            }
        }

        private void dodajKameroToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panelDodajKamero.Show();
        }

        private void izpisKamer()
        {
            //zanka ki odstrani vse prej dodane kamere
            textBox1.Text = kamereToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count.ToString();

            foreach (String kamera in kamere)
            {
                kamereToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.RemoveByKey(kamera);
            }

            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\kamere.txt");
            foreach (String kamera in kamere)
            {
                ToolStripDropDownButton btTemp = new ToolStripDropDownButton(kamera, null, kameraOnClick, kamera);
                file.WriteLine(kamera);

                //dodamo trenutno kamero, ki je v kamerah.txt
                kamereToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(btTemp);
            }
            file.Dispose();
            file.Close();
        }

        private void kameraOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //tbNaslovKamere.Text+=sender.ToString();
            imageUrl = "http://" + sender.ToString() + "/now.jpg";
        }

        private void izhodToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void preberiDatoteko()
        {
            String vrstica;
            // Read the file as one string.
            if (File.Exists(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\kamere.txt"))
            {
                kamere = new List<String>();
                StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\kamere.txt");
                while ((vrstica = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //zapis v list
                    kamere.Add(vrstica);
                    //doda v meni
                    ToolStripDropDownButton btTemp = new ToolStripDropDownButton(vrstica, null, kameraOnClick, vrstica);
                    kamereToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(btTemp);
                }
                myFile.Close();
            }
        }

        private void menuPobrisiKamere()
        {
            foreach (String kamera in kamere)
            {
                kamereToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.RemoveByKey(kamera);
            }
            kamere = new List<String>();
        }

        private void odpriToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create an instance of the open file dialog box.
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            // Set filter options and filter index.
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

            //openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            // Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialog box.
            DialogResult userClickedOK = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            //tbNaslovKamere.Text = userClickedOK.ToString();
            // Process input if the user clicked OK.
            if (userClickedOK.ToString().Equals("OK"))
            {
                menuPobrisiKamere();
                String vrstica;

                // Open the selected file to read.
                System.IO.Stream fileStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
                kamere = new List<String>();
                StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(fileStream);
                while ((vrstica = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //zapis v list
                    kamere.Add(vrstica);
                    //doda v meni
                    ToolStripDropDownButton btTemp = new ToolStripDropDownButton(vrstica, null, kameraOnClick, vrstica);
                    kamereToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(btTemp);
                }
                myFile.Dispose();
                myFile.Close();
                fileStream.Dispose();
                fileStream.Close();
                myFile.Close();
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }

        private void pobrišiKamereToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            menuPobrisiKamere();
        }

        private void zbrišiShranjeneKamereToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            menuPobrisiKamere();
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\kamere.txt");
            file.Dispose();
            file.Close();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            frm1.Size = new Size(100, frm1.Size.Height);
        }

        private bool RemoteFileExists(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                //Creating the HttpWebRequest
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
                request.Method = "HEAD";
                //Getting the Web Response.
                HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                //Returns TRUE if the Status code == 200
                return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch
            {
                //Any exception will returns false.
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will open Form and open link (host) and display image from `http://IP/HOSTNAME/now.jpg` , can be changed to somethin else. write the host in txt file ... A verry simple efective and cute application. After my optimization now need only 0-1 CPU time and max 70K memmory.

I hope you will find out usefull ... Is an .Net 3.5 application.